# Remove space before second column to maintain pdb formatting

Tags: text-processing

```
ATOM   9996  CG  GLU   622     -13.525  -7.714 -11.215  0.0136  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM   9997 2HG  GLU   622     -12.773  -7.608 -11.999 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9998 3HG  GLU   622     -13.121  -8.370 -10.441 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9999  CD  GLU   622     -14.803  -8.348 -11.783  0.8054  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM   10000  OE1 GLU   622     -15.541  -9.019 -11.024 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM   10001  OE2 GLU   622     -15.105  -8.223 -12.988 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM   10002  C   GLU   622     -13.072  -4.215  -9.499  0.5366  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM   10003  O   GLU   622     -13.537  -3.437 -10.330 -0.5819  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM   10004  N   TYR   623     -12.988  -3.858  -8.210 -0.4157  1.8240  0.1700
ATOM   10005  H   TYR   623     -12.684  -4.551  -7.536  0.2719  0.6000  0.0157
ATOM   10006  CA  TYR   623     -13.410  -2.540  -7.700 -0.0014  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM   10007  HA  TYR   623     -13.794  -1.927  -8.513  0.0876  1.3870  0.0157
ATOM   10008  CB  TYR   623     -14.530  -2.720  -6.667 -0.0152  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM   10009 2HB  TYR   623     -14.107  -3.312  -5.863  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   10010 3HB  TYR   623     -14.784  -1.738  -6.265  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   10011  CG  TYR   623     -15.831  -3.390  -7.081 -0.0011  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM   10012  CD1 TYR   623     -16.301  -3.357  -8.410 -0.1906  1.9080  0.0860
```

As seen in the format above, the lines after `10000 ATOM` are shown with one space shift. How can I specifically remove just one space before the second column in the file after line number 10000?

Tho output should be like:

```
ATOM   9995 3HB  GLU   622     -14.203  -5.702 -11.411 -0.0173  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9996  CG  GLU   622     -13.525  -7.714 -11.215  0.0136  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM   9997 2HG  GLU   622     -12.773  -7.608 -11.999 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9998 3HG  GLU   622     -13.121  -8.370 -10.441 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9999  CD  GLU   622     -14.803  -8.348 -11.783  0.8054  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10000  OE1 GLU   622     -15.541  -9.019 -11.024 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10001  OE2 GLU   622     -15.105  -8.223 -12.988 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10002  C   GLU   622     -13.072  -4.215  -9.499  0.5366  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10003  O   GLU   622     -13.537  -3.437 -10.330 -0.5819  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10004  N   TYR   623     -12.988  -3.858  -8.210 -0.4157  1.8240  0.1700
ATOM  10005  H   TYR   623     -12.684  -4.551  -7.536  0.2719  0.6000  0.0157
ATOM  10006  CA  TYR   623     -13.410  -2.540  -7.700 -0.0014  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM  10007  HA  TYR   623     -13.794  -1.927  -8.513  0.0876  1.3870  0.0157
ATOM  10008  CB  TYR   623     -14.530  -2.720  -6.667 -0.0152  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM  10009 2HB  TYR   623     -14.107  -3.312  -5.863  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM  10010 3HB  TYR   623     -14.784  -1.738  -6.265  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM  10011  CG  TYR   623     -15.831  -3.390  -7.081 -0.0011  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10012  CD1 TYR   623     -16.301  -3.357  -8.410 -0.1906  1.9080  0.0860
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to? That would make `10009 2HB` into `100092HB`. Or are the lines 10009 and 10010 wrong? Don't you want there to always be one space after the residue number? Your desired output sometimes has an extra character on the left and sometimes on the right? Don't you want all of them to be aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/ATOM *10000/,$ s/ATOM \( *\)\([0-9]*\)/ATOM\1\2/'
```

It uses an address range, from `/ATOM *10000/` to `$`, which stand for the first line matching ATOM + spaces + 10000, and the last line, respectively.

For each line in the address range, it replaces the ATOM followed by spaces, the number by everything ATOM, spaces without the first one, and the number.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. You could read the file and remove the space on all lines after whose second field is greater than 9999:

```
$ awk '$2>9999{sub(/ /,"")}1;' file 
ATOM   9996  CG  GLU   622     -13.525  -7.714 -11.215  0.0136  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM   9997 2HG  GLU   622     -12.773  -7.608 -11.999 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9998 3HG  GLU   622     -13.121  -8.370 -10.441 -0.0425  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM   9999  CD  GLU   622     -14.803  -8.348 -11.783  0.8054  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10000  OE1 GLU   622     -15.541  -9.019 -11.024 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10001  OE2 GLU   622     -15.105  -8.223 -12.988 -0.8188  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10002  C   GLU   622     -13.072  -4.215  -9.499  0.5366  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10003  O   GLU   622     -13.537  -3.437 -10.330 -0.5819  1.6612  0.2100
ATOM  10004  N   TYR   623     -12.988  -3.858  -8.210 -0.4157  1.8240  0.1700
ATOM  10005  H   TYR   623     -12.684  -4.551  -7.536  0.2719  0.6000  0.0157
ATOM  10006  CA  TYR   623     -13.410  -2.540  -7.700 -0.0014  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM  10007  HA  TYR   623     -13.794  -1.927  -8.513  0.0876  1.3870  0.0157
ATOM  10008  CB  TYR   623     -14.530  -2.720  -6.667 -0.0152  1.9080  0.1094
ATOM  10009 2HB  TYR   623     -14.107  -3.312  -5.863  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM  10010 3HB  TYR   623     -14.784  -1.738  -6.265  0.0295  1.4870  0.0157
ATOM  10011  CG  TYR   623     -15.831  -3.390  -7.081 -0.0011  1.9080  0.0860
ATOM  10012  CD1 TYR   623     -16.301  -3.357  -8.410 -0.1906  1.9080  0.0860
```

Alternatively, you can align everything:

```
$ perl -lane 'printf "%-5s%6s %-3s%4s%5d%8s%8s%8s%8s%8s\n",@F' file 
ATOM   9996 CG  GLU  622 -13.525  -7.714 -11.215  0.0136  1.9080
ATOM   9997 2HG GLU  622 -12.773  -7.608 -11.999 -0.0425  1.4870
ATOM   9998 3HG GLU  622 -13.121  -8.370 -10.441 -0.0425  1.4870
ATOM   9999 CD  GLU  622 -14.803  -8.348 -11.783  0.8054  1.9080
ATOM  10000 OE1 GLU  622 -15.541  -9.019 -11.024 -0.8188  1.6612
ATOM  10001 OE2 GLU  622 -15.105  -8.223 -12.988 -0.8188  1.6612
ATOM  10002 C   GLU  622 -13.072  -4.215  -9.499  0.5366  1.9080
ATOM  10003 O   GLU  622 -13.537  -3.437 -10.330 -0.5819  1.6612
ATOM  10004 N   TYR  623 -12.988  -3.858  -8.210 -0.4157  1.8240
ATOM  10005 H   TYR  623 -12.684  -4.551  -7.536  0.2719  0.6000
ATOM  10006 CA  TYR  623 -13.410  -2.540  -7.700 -0.0014  1.9080
ATOM  10007 HA  TYR  623 -13.794  -1.927  -8.513  0.0876  1.3870
ATOM  10008 CB  TYR  623 -14.530  -2.720  -6.667 -0.0152  1.9080
ATOM  10009 2HB TYR  623 -14.107  -3.312  -5.863  0.0295  1.4870
ATOM  10010 3HB TYR  623 -14.784  -1.738  -6.265  0.0295  1.4870
ATOM  10011 CG  TYR  623 -15.831  -3.390  -7.081 -0.0011  1.9080
ATOM  10012 CD1 TYR  623 -16.301  -3.357  -8.410 -0.1906  1.9080
```